# Power BI Table Matrix Visualization with alternate Colors

Tags: office365, powerbi

The Table in Power BI for Office 365 shows in plain simple view in While Background and font colors can be changed,! is there any visualization which I can import which shows rows in alternate colors

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  Perhaps you can write one :)?  http://www.github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals